# Using animation for WebView page changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I've been scouring the web looking for examples of how I could incorporate animation into my UIWebView control but am coming up blank.

I am not picky as to the animation (I can mess with it once I understand how to attach it to the actions), I just want something more than just a stark transition from one web page to another, curled pages, animation from left (old page) to right (new page), whatever will do.

Can someone post an example or direct me to a page that explains how I might do this?  I read the docs on CATransition but I still don't see how to incorporate it into my UIWebView navigation.

Comment: Did you want to control the animation when navigating between webpages when you click on a link in the web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around I got the effect I wanted, I probably need to tweak it a bit but here's what I came up with:

Before performing a loadRequest (and I've changed my code for now so that I capture all page changes via shouldStartLoadWithRequest and then set the new page manually using webview loadRequest) I go to a curl animation routine I wrote called animatePage:

```
- (void) animatePage 
{
  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setDelegate:self];
  [animation setDuration:1.0f];
  animation.startProgress = 0.5;
  animation.endProgress   = 1;
  [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
  [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];

  //[animation setType:kcat];
  [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionMoveIn];

  [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
  [animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
  [animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
  [[myWebView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"WebPageCurl"];
}
```

So to animate the page changes with a curling upward page animation I basically do:

```
[self animatePage];
[myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

I can call the `animatePage` routine either before or after the loadRequest, it doesn't matter much.

I know this might not be the "right" way to get the job done but it does seem to get the job done.  Like I said, I need to dial it in here and there but I'm happy with the result so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift:-

```
let animation = CATransition()//= [CATransition animation];
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.startProgress = 0.5
    animation.endProgress = 1
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)//kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)//kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut
    animation.type = "pageCurl"

    animation.subtype = kCATransitionMoveIn
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = "extended"
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    webView?.layer.add(animation, forKey: "WebPageCurl")
```